# how to connect my JFrame to my Dotsgame program

Tags: java, swing

When I enter my details in the JFrame and click enter  the dots game to doesn't popup

code for `JFrame`

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   this.setVisible(false);
   new DotsAndBoxes2().setVisible(true);
   this.dispose();
```

and this is some of the code for the DOTS game.

```
package javaapplication5;


import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;


public class DotsAndBoxes2



            extends JFrame
            implements ActionListener, ItemListener, Runnable
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your DotsAndBoxes2 should actually be extending JFrame instead of Applet.   Either way your code looks horrible, I would suggest you don't use a GUI Builder to create the code and it makes debugging difficult.