# Launch Applet from JFrame

Tags: java, swing

How can I launch the following applet game from a JFrame?

This is the code for the applet game

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DotsAndBoxes2
            extends Applet
            implements ActionListener, ItemListener, Runnable
```

This is the code for my JFrame

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       this.setVisible(false);
       new DotsAndBoxes2().setVisible(true);
       this.dispose();


    }
```

Comment: This is just a variation of the question you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585788/how-to-connect-my-jframe-to-my-dotsgame-program

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the applet and generate a jar file for applets (see how in a applet tutorial)

Then create a simply HTML page witch invoke your applet on screen.

From your JFrame use the method Desktop.browse from the Desktop Java API (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) and pass the URL of the HTML file you created in the last step.